# What is wrong with this SQLite3 statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have written this SQLite statement and I am getting syntax error on the following line:

```
update List SET number = (CASE WHEN number>=3 then number++ WHEN number=1 then 3 ELSE number END) WHERE listKey=3;
```

The error is:

> SQL error: near "WHEN": syntax error

I tried various versions, adding braces at places and all, but can't figure out the error. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If SQLite uses "++" syntax, I've never seen it.  Try `then number + 1` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. Actually I am trying to write query something like: if(number >=3 && nextNumberinlist= number+1) then number++ else number. Can you give me some idea how to do this.

Comment: What is "nextNumberInList"?  Is it the number from the "next" row in the table?  And what is the "next" row (SQL does not have any concept of default row order).  I suggest you post a complete version of your question (including the table structure, sample input data, and sample desired output) in a separate question.